# Encrypt an existing (important point) directory

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, directory, 16.10

I'd like to encrypt an **existing** directory. I know there exists a software like cryptkeeper which could do such thins, but it doesn't allow to encrypt existing folder. With that software, we have to create one encrypt directory and put the existing directory in the new one. Could anyone be able to explain a clever way to do that from the shell or with an adapted software?

In fact, I'd like this file to be encrypted to protect it as much as possible (e.g., NSA). If I send this file to another user in other country, I want this file to be protected from hacker.

**P.S.** This file is very important. I work on a project since many years, and I want anyone could access this file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can  you update your question with - What do you want done with the original files after encryption? What do you want done with the original directory after encryption? Do you want the encrypted files all in one master file that and the real names can only be viewed with password or do you want individual encrypted file names visible with an extra extension? Is this a one shot deal or will you add a new file tomorrow that needs to be encrypted?

Comment: What level of encryption do you want? ie Just from wife / boss, or from NSA? Does it have to be in Terminal (character mode) or can it be through Nauitilus file manager (GUI)?

Comment: If you are looking for a private/safe way to transfer a folder across countries (over the internet), I would prefer to use some cloud service, such as an encrypted owncloud/nextcloud account, or an encrypted seafile folder. Otherwise, you could as well compress it with a strong password and send it.

Comment: @Ludenticus At least, could you tell me to put a password on the directory that contains those files?

Comment: Of course, the problem with the encrypted cloud is that your hosting provider would be able to read your file names (not the content).

Comment: When you use an encrypted owncloud (check as admin before submitting anything) ANY file will be encrypted

Comment: Could you write a full answer to this question with reference please?

Comment: Do you need *transparent* access to the encrypted directory, i. e. do you need to access them like on any file system while they're decrypted and encrypted on the fly while programs read or write them? Or would it be enough to manually decrypt a file, modify it and then re-encrypt it?

Comment: Thanks for you interest @DavidFoerster, but it is fine; Ludenticus answered well my question.

Answer (score 3):

Use gpg. First, have the recipient of the files do:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

and follow the prompts to generate a 4096-bit RSA key. Then have the recipient do:

```
gpg --armor --export (name)
```

where `name` is the name given for the key in the first step. Then send the output of the command to you. Then you do:

```
gpg --armor --import
```

and paste in the key. For increased security, do:

```
gpg --list-keys --fingerprint
```

and confirm the fingerprint with the recipient by phone (the public key does not need to be sent confidentially, but it does need to not have been tampered with). Then, to encrypt a file for sending, do:

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient (name) <file.clear >file.encrypted
```

To make a single file out of a directory tree, use tar:

```
tar -f file.clear -C /path/to/directory -c .
```

You don't need to compress the `tar` file, as `gpg` does its own compression. The recipient can use `gpg --decrypt` to decrypt and then `tar -x` to unpack the tar file.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to transfer *safely* folders and files over the Internet. Of course, whenever you put some archive on someone else's disk you run the risk that the space is «jeopardized», i.e. that it has been somehow *hacked*. That's why the best (but absolutely useless by today standards) method would be to keep your files at home, on a good safe vault. So, you have to *compromise*. This means that you have to take extra cautions to avoid mistakes.

I'd suggest the following procedures. They have advantages and disadvantages. In any case it is a good practice to employ strong passwords.

**First option**

[Owncloud](https://owncloud.org) or [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com). At this stage they are pretty similar, as Nextcloud is a recent fork from mid-2016. If you choose to use either of them, you will have to set your own server (which is best), or you can hire a shared hosting service, or even a VPS. As an admin, be sure to enable both the encryption module as well as the server side encryption. If some has access to the file within the server they will only see the file name but the content will be useless. You can share files or directories. Ubuntu has an official owncloud client to sync.

[image: Server side encryption]

**Second option**

[Seafile](https://seafile.de/) offers the option to encrypt a folder, but in this case you can only share the whole folder. You will have to register with them to download and install your own server. It seems easier to pay their service.

[image: Seafile]

**Third option**

If you don't plan to share frequently, you can always compress a folder, encrypt it and send it, provided that it is not that large.

First, install `seahorse-nautilus`. Then, quit and restart Nautilus. You can now compress and encrypt. Your receiver must know the password: use [Telegram](https://telegram.me)'s Secure Chat or some other private communication service.

[image: Compress]